# Connection between auto scaling and ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, autoscaling

I have read that we can configure Auto Scaling to used CloudWatch metrics to scale in/or a pool of EC2 instances.

I'm curious to understand how ELB gets to know there is an EC2 instance added/removed to the Auto Scaling Group, so it does send workload to the newly added instance ? (or stop sending workload to the instance that has been removed?)

Regards,
Pascal

Comment: This is done automatically, that's why it is called `Auto Scaling` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set them up, you associate the Auto Scaling group with the Elastic Load Balancer.  The Auto Scaling Group then notifies the Elastic Load Balancer when instances are added or removed.